# programmatically add property do ActionScript Object (metaprogramming)

Tags: actionscript-3, dynamic-languages

I have an AS3 Object: {p1:"..", p2:".."}
I want con create another object that contains the first one in a property whose name is defined by a variable:

```
var propertyName:String = "myName";
var myObj = new Object();
myObj.something_that_creates_a_property_named_as_propertyName({p1:"..", p2:".."})
```

does it make any sense?

Comment: This is not really metaprogramming. I do not know the exact word, but it is posible because actionscript is a dynamic language.

Comment: you're right.. I never really understood what metaprogramming was, I'll read some more about it!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
var propertyName:String = "myName";
var myObj = new Object();
myObj[propertyName] = {p1:"..", p2:".."};
```